# Why Does Inpainting Fail, and How to Fix it?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a 100x100 numpy array which is about 47% nans. I would like to inpaint the smaller connected regions of nan. Here is the input array, nans are white.

[image: input]

Here are the nans (white):

```
m_nans = np.isnan(input).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image: nans]

Here I select connected regions of nans with areas below an arbitrary threshold:

```
n,nans_labelled,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(m_nans)
labels = np.where(stats[1:, 4] < 500)[0] + 1
m_nans_small = np.isin(nans_labelled, labels).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image: nans connected small]

Now I would like to inpaint the regions above, lets start with radius 3.

```
inpainted = cv2.inpaint(input, m_nans_small, 3, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

[image: inpaint ns r3]

And these are the inpainted regions:

[image: nans inpainted]

Then I tried increasing the radius to 10 which resulted in nothing being inpainted. Then I tried dilating the mask, which led to nans being inpainted. Thinking higher radius caused only nans to be inpainted, I tried again with all nans masked (`m_nans`). The result was identical for the regions I was actually interested in inpainting, `m_nans_small`. Then I tried the smallest radius possible (1) with `m_nans_small` and while that inpaints more regions, it fails to fully inpaint the region of interest. A radius of 1 is also too small compared to the area of the regions I want to inpaint.

[image: inpaint ns r1]

Interestingly, if I try to inpaint recursively - inpaint the image above masked with the nans from that image intersected with the original mask - there is no noticeable improvement, even with the smallest radius. This suggests that inpainting does not fail from a lack of paint. Even two-pixel regions completely surrounded by valid pixels fail to inpaint.

```
m_nans_small_remaining = np.isnan(inpainted) & m_nans_small 
inpainted2 = cv2.inpaint(inpainted, m_nans_small_remaining, 1, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

[image: second inpaint ns r1 using remaining small connected nans]

At last I tried inpainting a dilated `m_nans`. With a radius of 1 it inpaints almost anything, but the result is shoddy due to the small radius, and it overwrites good data. With a radius of 50 it inpaints everything with nans.

I have some idea why inpainting fails, but I would like to know for sure. Then I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: My code is there?

Comment: OK. All spread out. I was not expecting that. Sorry.

Comment: Your regions are too big/thick for the type of inpainting available in OpenCV or Skimage, which is for scratches. You likely need a patch based approach.

Comment: @fmw42 Are you sure? I filter out the large components, and the documentation doesn't say anything about scratches. Also doesn't explain why opencv won't inpaint the remaining small 1-5 pixel components in the final image. And I don't understand why the small 1-5 pixel components in the initial mask aren't inpainted unless the radius is 1.

Comment: @fmw42 Can you recommend any python libraries for patch-based inpainting?

Comment: There are none that I know about.

Comment: I went with `cv.xphoto.INPAINT_FSR_BEST` as that works with with large regions and preserves isophotes quite well.

Comment: I did not know about that, sorry. Glad you found something that works.